# Append directory to filename per lookup table values

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to append the parent directory's name into filename based on an on/off switch and fileextension **stored in a lookup table**?

**For example**, if  a directory is ending with ...`=d5`, then, per the lookup table, all `raw_file` (`nef, jpg, avi`) filenames **within** the ...`=d5` directory are to be appended with 1 level parent directory name like `dirname_origfilename.nef`. If `['append_dir_to_filename'] = 0`, then do NOT append the directory name.

Filename pattern **before** and **after**:

```
CWD                                      
    01_camdirab=d5                       
          /aaa/ .nef,.jpg,.avi,.wav
    02_camdirxyz=g7                     
          /bbb/ddd/ .cr2,.jpg,.mp4
    03_camdire012345=a9                  
          /yyy/kkk/xxx/ .mp4,.jpg,.avi,.thm
    04_camdire012345                     
          / .mp4,.jpg,.avi

CWD                                      
    01_camdirab=d5                       
          /aaa/aaa_.nef, aaa_.jpg, aaa_.avi, .wav            #appended raw files
    02_camdirxyz=g7                      
          /bbb/ddd/.cr2,.jpg,.mp4                            #not appended, 'append_dir_to_filename'] = 0 
    03_camdire012345=a9                  
          /yyy/kkk/xxx/ xxx_.mp4, xxx_.jpg, xxx_.avi, .thm   #appended raw files
    04_camdire012345                     
          /.mp4,.jpg,.avi                   #not appended, dir not in lookup,
```

The code (unable to link properly to lookup table):

```
import os
import glob
import shutil
cwd = os.getcwd()

config = {
   'append_dir_to_filename' : ('d5', 'a9'),
    'd5': ('nef', 'jpg', 'avi'),
    'a9': ('mp4', 'jpg', 'avi')
}
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(cwd):
  prefix = os.path.basename(root)
  if (prefix[-2:] in config['append_dir_to_filename']):
    for f in files:
      cameraObj = config[prefix[-2:]]
      for extension in cameraObj.supported_extensions:
        if (f.endswith('.' + extension)):
          os.rename(os.path.join(root, f), os.path.join(root, "{}_{}".format(prefix, f)))
```

Actual lookup table entry for 1 camera. There are 10 cameras, so 10x this.

```
config['d5']['append_dir_to_filename'] = 1
config['d5']['device_name'] = 'Nikon-D5'
config['d5']['raw_file'] = ('nef', 'jpg', 'avi')
config['d5']['sup_file'] = ('jpg', 'wav')
config['d5']['to_else_file'] = ('avi')
config['d5']['timestamp'] = ('lwt')
config['d5']['md5'] = 1
config['d5']['code1'] = 'FAR'
config['d5']['gps'] = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't actually showed the part where you use your look-up table in code, however you can begin by restructuring your loop-up table to simplify your problem. Something like this:

```
config = {
   'append_dir_to_filename' : ('d5', 'a9'),
    'd5': ('nef', 'jpg', 'avi'),
    'a9': ('mp4', 'jpg', 'avi')
}
```

These modifications assume that you don't need information for the directories that you don't want to append to the file name. With this in place, the rest of the code is pretty straightforward:

```
prefix = os.path.basename(root)
if (prefix[-2:] in config['append_dir_to_filename']):
   for f in files:
     for extension in config[prefix[-2:]]:
       if (f.endswith('.' + extension)):
         #Do the appending business here
```

Haven't really tested the code, but this should work for you.

**EDIT**: In case you follow in the suggestion in my comment, use the below code:

```
prefix = os.path.basename(root)
if (prefix[-2:] in config['append_dir_to_filename']):
   for f in files:
     cameraObj = config[prefix[-2:]]
     for extension in cameraObj.supported_extensions:
       if (f.endswith('.' + extension)):
         #Do the appending business here
```

and the look-up table will be like so:

```
config = {
   'append_dir_to_filename' : ('d5', 'a9'),
    'd5': Camera(...list of properties...),
    'a9': Camera(...list of properties...)
}
```

**EDIT**: Ok, I essentially had to write the entire code from scratch. This version definitely works.

```
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()
config = {
   'append_dir_to_filename' : ('d5', 'a9'),
    'd5': ('nef', 'jpg', 'avi'),
    'a9': ('mp4', 'jpg', 'avi')
}

cameraDirs = [os.path.join(cwd, x) for x in next(os.walk(cwd))[1] if x[-2:] in config['append_dir_to_filename']]
for cameraDir in cameraDirs:
    cameraShortName = cameraDir[-2:]
    for rootDir, _, files in os.walk(cameraDir):
        prefix = os.path.basename(rootDir)
        for file in files:
            if (any(x for x in config[cameraShortName] if file.endswith(x))):
                os.rename(os.path.join(rootDir, file), os.path.join(rootDir, "{}_{}".format(prefix, file)))
```

Comment: Thank you, will test it. I appreciate your comment also on lookup table optimal structure. The lookup table in my orig question is a reduced version of (an extract from) the actual lookup table, as there are 10 camera types (d5, g7...), each with 8 parametres (raw_files, append_dir_to_filename, long camera_name, support_files,...) and some of these parameters (like "raw-files" have multiple values (.nef, .tif, .jpg [the sequential order of these values is relevant for filing]).  So... with this complexity in mind, are you still suggesting of restructuring the lookup table?

Comment: Here is my suggestion. Keep 'append_dir_to_filename' the same as I have suggested in my solution. So with your full scenario, it will now have 10 values. For each of those values, have a key in the look up table that maps to a Camera object instead of any built-in type. The Camera object in turn contains all the properties you mentioned, like list of raw files, camera name, support files etc. This will obviously require changes to the suggested code, so I will make an edit to give you a hint.

Comment: Thanks. See the very end of  orig question for an actual table entry for 1 camera. I have 10 of these. So not sure how to handle the `'d5': Camera(...list of properties...),` format...? Putting everything in one line for 1 camera? 10 lines for 10 cameras?

Comment: Not necessary in one line. Just that the object needs to be initialized before assigning them to a key in the look-up table. Object initialization can be done on separate lines like so: d5 = Camera('Nikon-D5', 'lwt', ..) and then use it in the look-up table as 'd5': d5. Unfortunately, you will have to create 10 objects since the data is unique for each one of them

Comment: Re **code:** It does nor rename files, no error message. I inserted into the orig question what I am trying out from your answer. feel free to edit. What I am missing? Re **lookup:** thank you for the thoughts, let think it over.

Comment: Made the code changes in the original post. Essentially, the problem was with prefix = os.path.basename(cwd), it should have been prefix = os.path.basename(root). Let me know if you face any more problems.

Comment: I am trying to troubleshoot. Is `if (prefix[-2]` implies that the files to rename are at -2 dir level from the cmareadir=d5?  If so, that's not good, as different cameras have different dir depths (as shown in the example, a9 has 3 subdris below the cameradir=a9.

Comment: Made changes in code in both places. There was a little typo. Try running the updated version

Comment: No luck unfortunately. I am trying your edit directly from the original question. I am using the same dir structure as in my example, so should append `.jpg` files with `aaa` and `xxx` for folders ending with  `=d5` and `a9`, respectively.

Comment: I continue to play with it to make it work, will report back.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thank you again! In case you are not tired :)
 [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47173694](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47173694/preempt-lookup-table-rule-in-file-rename).