# Preempt lookup table rule in file rename

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code below prefix select filenames with parent directory name per lookup table rules. It works perfectly.

Yet, how I insert into this code **an exception**, so any and all files that are **one (1) level below the CWD** (i.e., files in `=d5`, `=a9`, etc. non-recursive) **are never appended** with parent directory name? Like preempting or overriding the lookup table **if** that calls for appending directory name.

Filename pattern **before** and **after** (see the first two ...`=d5` examples, they differ with `aaa` subdir):

```
CWD                                      
    00_camdirabde=d5                       
          /.nef,.jpg,.avi,.wav         #files 1 level below CWD -> NEVER append (even if =d5 string call for it from lookup table)
    01_camdirab=d5                       
          /aaa/ .nef,.jpg,.avi,.wav    #files not 1 level below CWD -> append per lookup table rule
    02_camdirxyz=g7                     
          /bbb/ddd/ .cr2,.jpg,.mp4
    03_camdire012345=a9                  
          /yyy/kkk/xxx/ .mp4,.jpg,.avi,.thm
    04_camdire012345                     
          / .mp4,.jpg,.avi

CWD                                      
    00_camdirabde=d5                       
          /.nef,.jpg,.avi,.wav                        #NOT appended files
    01_camdirab=d5                       
          /aaa/aaa_.nef, aaa_.jpg, aaa_.avi, .wav     #appended files
    02_camdirxyz=g7                      
          /bbb/ddd/.cr2,.jpg,.mp4                     #not appended, 'append_dir_to_filename'] = 0 
    03_camdire012345=a9                  
          /yyy/kkk/xxx/ xxx_.mp4, xxx_.jpg, xxx_.avi, .thm   #appended files
    04_camdire012345                     
          /.mp4,.jpg,.avi                                    #not appended, dir not in lookup,
```

Code:

```
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()
config = {
   'append_dir_to_filename' : ('d5', 'a9'),
    'd5': ('nef', 'NED', 'jpg', 'JPG', 'avi', 'AVI'),
    'a9': ('mp4', 'MP4', 'jpg', 'JPG', 'avi', 'AVI')
}

cameraDirs = [os.path.join(cwd, x) for x in next(os.walk(cwd))[1] if x[-2:] in config['append_dir_to_filename']]
for cameraDir in cameraDirs:
    cameraShortName = cameraDir[-2:]
    for rootDir, _, files in os.walk(cameraDir):
        prefix = os.path.basename(rootDir)
        for file in files:
            if (any(x for x in config[cameraShortName] if file.endswith(x))):
                os.rename(os.path.join(rootDir, file), os.path.join(rootDir, "{}_{}".format(prefix, file)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go, this will make sure that directories with camera names ending won't be appended to the files. Just before you try to rename the file, you need to perform an additional check, which is done by the below code fragment.

```
prefix[-2:] not in config['append_dir_to_filename']
```

This simply checks if the current directory being considered is not part of the camera directories (1st level directories) defined in the look-up table above. The complete code is as below:

```
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()
config = {
   'append_dir_to_filename' : ('d5', 'a9'),
    'd5': ('nef', 'jpg', 'avi'),
    'a9': ('mp4', 'jpg', 'avi')
}

cameraDirs = [os.path.join(cwd, x) for x in next(os.walk(cwd))[1] if x[-2:] in config['append_dir_to_filename']]
for cameraDir in cameraDirs:
    cameraShortName = cameraDir[-2:]
    for rootDir, _, files in os.walk(cameraDir):
        prefix = os.path.basename(rootDir)
        for file in files:
            if (any(x for x in config[cameraShortName] if file.endswith(x)) and prefix[-2:] not in config['append_dir_to_filename']):
                os.rename(os.path.join(rootDir, file), os.path.join(rootDir, "{}_{}".format(prefix, file)))
```

Comment: You could of course comment your answer to explain where the OP went wrong and how did you fix that. This could help future visitors to this question. Just code is only of limited educational value.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @hepretendprogrammer: I placed the lookup table structure, key, object for debate [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47185955](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47185955/lookup-table-optimal-structure-object-before-key). Thanks for your help!